# Negative regex for finding text which do not contain certain characters

Tags: java, regex, groovy

What is the regex for "Find me all the files with the following text but not ending with .zip or .md5"

So I have 3 files:

```
test-2016-123.zip......zip file
test-2016-123..........directory file
test-2016-123.MD5......checksum file
```

I want to select the middle file `test-2016-123` and want to ignore file with file extentions like .zip or .md5 etc.

What would be the regular expression to accomplish this?

So far I have something like this:

```
test-*+[^.\]
```

But this obviously does not work. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this `(^test).((?!(zip|md5)$).)*$`

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work for me. Perhaps I'm doing something wrong. I tested here https://regex101.com/r/8oyse9/1

Comment: Sorry, there was so many application to test regex. I am using notepad ++ to test regex and work with that code. 
But, if you can modify a little of code, it's will work. Just remove `^` and the code will work on that site.

Comment: Yea it worked for me on notepad++, not sure why it doesn't work online. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I am not expert in Regex but in `(^test).((?!(zip|md5)$).)*$` will match any other extension if there are in text like .txt , .pdf 
in that condition you can Use this one 
Try this

```
^test-(\w+\-(\w+)$)
```

this will ignore all of extension and give You proper match ..